# custom Table-like ViewGroup

Tags: android, user-interface

Can I somehow (preferably simply) make my custom ViewGroup that acts loosely like Table - spans cells to the largest width of column?
Using TableLayout is not an solution for me, I need to make the width modifications on my own list of views, since not all of them would be direct children.

So far I've tried to extend TableLayout and copy some of its methods to make them work with own list of views instead of children, but I got lost.

I'd also approciate a general answer, how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use RecyclerView to achieve this, you have to use **`Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager`**, by default there is an `onSelectionListener()` in case you want to support selection inside the grid.